# Calling C# WCF json services by javascript and html5

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, wcf

I have a difficulty in calling a WCF service (json) from javascript. it is a simple service that i have created for to get the data from the database. user should be able to give the username and the password from the HTML5 website, on click of the submit button, the service should be called.

this is the service interface

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate = "/getLogin", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
        int getLogin(string username, string password);
```

and this is the service method

```
public int getLogin(string username, string password)
    {
        var conString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("MyDBConnectionStrings");
        var sqlConn = new SqlConnection(conString);           
        var restID = 0;
        var user_name = "";
        var pass_word = "";

        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();
            var query = "select * from Restaurant where businesscode = '" + username + "' and password = '" + password + "'";
            var createCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConn);

            createCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            var dr = createCommand.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                user_name = dr["BusinessCode"].ToString();
                pass_word = dr["password"].ToString();
                restID = Convert.ToInt32(dr["RestuarantID"].ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                return restID;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            sqlConn.Close();
        }
        return restID;

    }
```

and this is the javascript function that i used to call the service upon clicking the button.

```
function loginService()
{
   var businesscode = document.getElementById("buscode").value; 
   var password = document.getElementById("pass").value; 

   var serviceUrl = "http://localhost:18933/Service1.svc/getLogin";

   var dataString='username=' + businesscode + '&password=' + password;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: serviceUrl,
        data: dataString,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        if(result == 1)
        {
         alert("log successful");
        }
        else
        {
        alert("fail");
        }
    }


});}
```

i dont know where i went wrong. when i click the submit button where i have called the function, no response from the website and no error showing in the console. if someone can help me in someway it would be a big help. thanks..

Comment: Did you inpect the request body?

Comment: your data (the dataString variable) is not in JSON format.